# Generic Type only accept specific types and test them

Tags: typescript, generics

I have an endpoint that will return some total amounts that can be grouped according to what the client sends.

The client currently has three options:

- Send null, which the backend groups everything and returns the total amount.
- Send "Employee", which the backend groups by employee and returns the total amount per employee.
- Send "PaymentMethod", which the backend groups by Payment Method and return the total amount per payment method.

On my React client (Typescript) I wanted to abstract this, and thus I was thinking on declaring the method something as:

```
export interface ITransactionsApi {
    GetResume<T extends Employee | PaymentMethod | void>(request: GetTransactionsResumeRequest): Promise<GetTransactionsResumeResponse>;
}
```

Then, when callinc this method I could either:

```
const allGrouped = await api.GetResume<void>(request);
const groupedByEmployee = await api.GetResume<Employee>(request);
const groupedByPaymentMethod = await api.GetResume<PaymentMethod>(request);
```

Now my implementation would be something like this:

```
 const GetResume = async <T extends Employee | PaymentMethod | void>(request: GetTransactionsResumeRequest) => {
    let url = '';
    const args: string[] = [];
    
    if(T is Employee) {
        url = '/api/Transaction/resume/Employee'
    }

    if(T is void) {
        url = '/api/Transaction/resume'
    }

    if(T is PaymentMethod) {
        url = '/api/Transaction/resume/PaymentMethod'
    }

    url = `${url}?${args.join('&')}`;

    const r = await httpClient.httpGet(url);
    return await parseResponse<GetTransactionsResumeResponse>(r);
}
```

Obviously, the above doesn't compile (and thus my doubt). What is the best approach to something like this?

Comment: You have to pass it as a normal arg. Generics in typescript are erased since there’s no concept in JavaScript

Comment: I’d personally just write separate functions

Comment: This is impossible as asked; you'd need to refactor as the above comments suggest. See the linked q/a for more information.